# How to export overlay glow

Tags: gimp, transparency

i made the following image:

- lowest layer: solid black
- middle layer: some white brush painting
- highest layer: solid red with Overlay mode

this gives me a nice glowing effect, which i would like to export to transparent PNG.
but when i set the black layer to invisble the glow is gone.

[image]

Comment: can you upload the file?

Comment: isnt my description clear enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not Gimp is the algorithm used to Overlay the layer which depends in Light and Dark colors.

So, to get the effect you want follow this steps:

**Go to the layers stack > Right Click > Click Merge Visible Layers**

[image]

**Click Merge**

[image]

**Go to Layer > Transparency > Color to Alpha**

[image]

**Select Black in the Color to Alpha Color Picker > Click OK (Two times)**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you won't see this but thank you so much.
I have been struggling as hell with that for...weeks!!!
God bless you